# Taxonomy and Custom Post type with Collpase

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I'm in trouble with Bootstrap and Wordpress.

I want to get Taxonomy list to expand (show custom posts from Taxonomy). But it is hard!!!!

Its basically a custom sidebar

My code:

```
<h3>
    Portfólio
</h3>


<?php   

$catprod = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria-produto',
            'order'    => 'DESC'
     )); // Todas as categorias


$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'produto'
     );

$prodtype = new WP_Query($args);


?>




   <div class="panel-group">

       <div class="panel-heading">
        <?php foreach( $catprod as $cat ) { ?>
           <h3 class="panel-title">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <?php echo $cat->name ?>
               </a>
           </h3>

           <div id="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
             <div class="panel-body">
                  <?php foreach( $prodtype as $prod ) { ?>
                      <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php the_field('titulo') ?>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                  <?php } ?>
             </div>
           </div>
        <?php } ?>  
       </div>  

   </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? _It is hard_ is hardly an explanation,

Comment: you have to use `WP_Query` inside `foreach` loop and use `tax_query` as  i mentioned in code snippet below

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<h3>
    Portfólio
</h3>

<?php   

$catprod = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'categoria-produto',
            'order'     => 'DESC',
            'parent'    =>0, 
            'hide_empty' => false,
     )); // Todas as categorias




?>
   <div class="panel-group">

       <div class="panel-heading">
        <?php foreach( $catprod as $cat ): ?>
           <h3 class="panel-title">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <?php echo $cat->name ?>
               </a>
           </h3>
           <?php 

           $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'produto',
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'categoria-produto',
                            'terms' => $cat->slug,
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'include_children' => true,
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        )
                    ),

             );

            $prodtype = new WP_Query($args);

           ?>
           <div id="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
             <div class="panel-body">
                  <?php while( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post(); ?>
                      <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
             </div>
           </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>  
       </div>  

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Now it works...

<h3>
    Portfólio
</h3>


<?php   

$catprod = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria-produto',
            'order'    => 'DESC'
     )); 


?>




   <div class="panel-group">

       <div class="panel-heading">

        <?php foreach( $catprod as $cat ) { ?>
           <h3 class="panel-title">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <?php echo $cat->name ?>
               </a>
           </h3>

                <!-- expand -->
                   <div id="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <?php //foreach( $catprod as $prod ) { ?> 

                        <?php   
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'produto',
                            //'posts_per_page' => 6,
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'categoria-produto',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $cat->slug
                                )
                            )
                        );
                        $content = new WP_Query( $args );       
                        ?>                            

                     <div class="panel-body">
                       <?php while ( $content->have_posts() ) : $content->the_post(); ?>                         
                          <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php the_field('titulo') ?>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                       <?php wp_reset_query() ?>                                  
                     </div>


                <?php //} ?>
                   </div>
                <!--/expand -->   

        <?php } ?>  


       </div>  

   </div>
```